# The best way to print info from a dgv

Tags: c#, arrays, printing, datagridview

I have a dgv where I add many products and codes, values etc, for the products, then I have the need to print out the contents.

Initially, I'm using this code:

```
private int _Line = 0;
        void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Font myFont = new Font("Courier New", 08, FontStyle.Underline, GraphicsUnit.Point);

            float lineHeight = myFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics) + 4;

            float yLineTop = e.MarginBounds.Top;



            int b = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;            
            for (int _Line = 0; _Line < b; _Line++)
            {
                if (yLineTop + lineHeight > e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    return;
                }

                //e.Graphics.DrawString("TEST: " + _Line, myFont, Brushes.Black,
                // new PointF(e.MarginBounds.Left, yLineTop));

                Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
                //Font font = new Font("Courier New", 8);
                //float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
                int startX = 50;
                int startY = 65;
                int Offset = 40;
                graphics.DrawString("Welcome to Bakery Shop - "+DateTime.Now+".", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
                Offset = Offset + 20;
                string underLine = "------------------------------------------";
                graphics.DrawString(underLine, new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
                Offset = Offset + 20;
                graphics.DrawString("" + label1.Text + "", new Font("Courier New", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
                Offset = Offset + 20;
                graphics.DrawString("Item", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
                graphics.DrawString("Cod.", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX+80, startY + Offset);
                graphics.DrawString("Nome", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 160, startY + Offset);
                graphics.DrawString("Valor", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 240, startY + Offset);
                graphics.DrawString("Qtd.", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 320, startY + Offset);
                graphics.DrawString("Parcial", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 400, startY + Offset);
                graphics.DrawString("Desconto", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 510, startY + Offset);
                graphics.DrawString("Subtotal", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 600, startY + Offset);
                Offset = Offset + 20;
                int a = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)

                {

                    graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Index+1), new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset + 30);
                    graphics.DrawString("\t" + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value), new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 10, startY + Offset + 30);
                    graphics.DrawString("\t" + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value), new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 90, startY + Offset + 30);
                    graphics.DrawString("\t" + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value), new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 180, startY + Offset + 30);
                    graphics.DrawString("\t" + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value), new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 270, startY + Offset + 30);
                    graphics.DrawString("\t" + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value), new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 340, startY + Offset + 30);
                    graphics.DrawString("\t" + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value), new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 430, startY + Offset + 30);
                    graphics.DrawString("\t" + Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value), new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 570, startY + Offset + 30);
                    Offset = Offset + 20;

                    graphics.DrawString("\t" +), new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 570, startY + Offset + 30);
                    Offset = Offset + 20;

                }
                Offset = Offset + 20;
                Offset = Offset + 20;
                Offset = Offset + 20;
                graphics.DrawString("Total - " + textBox7.Text + ".", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
                Offset = Offset + 20;
                graphics.DrawString("Troco - " + textBox3.Text + ".", new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
                Offset = Offset + 20;
                yLineTop += lineHeight;
            }

            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
```

Beside some strange behaviour that I'm going to work later, I noticed that a single line has to have each element well aligned so that, it doesn't print information above informartion.

Then I thought that, If I convert the full row and add a space between each cell, and print the array, it would never display info above info, even when as example the "code" is too big, so it would not be showed above/mixed with the "name" column.

Is this a better way? How do I start to make that? Because everywhere I look at, the solution is to pass a single cell as string.

In my case, each row, would have 6 columns, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed like this:

```
int a = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;                
                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)               

                {
                    string[] dgvtoarray = { Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Index + 1), Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value), Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value), Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value), Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value), Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value), Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value), Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value) };
                    var result = string.Join(" | ", dgvtoarray);

                    graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(result), new Font("Courier New", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset + 30);
                    Offset = Offset + 20;

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to print from datagridview is transferring data to Excel worksheet.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws;
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excell = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = Excell.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)Excell.ActiveSheet;
            Excell.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }

        int i = 1;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn clm in dgw.Columns)
        {
            ws.Cells[2, i] = clm.Name;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xcell = ws.Cells[2, i];
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Borders brd1 = xcell.Borders;
            xcell.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

            brd1.LineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
            brd1.Weight = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium;
            i++;
        }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row = ws.Cells[2, i];
        row.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range fcell = ws.Cells[1, 1];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range lcell = ws.Cells[1, i - 1];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range space = ws.get_Range(fcell, lcell);
        space.Merge(true);
        space.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

        ws.Cells[1, 1] = //Your text here
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Borders brd = space.Borders;
        aralik.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

        int m = 3;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in dgw.Rows)
        {
            for (int p = 1; p < i; p++)
            {
                if (rows.Cells[p-1].Value.ToString()=="")
                {
                    string str = string.Empty;

                    foreach (Control item in cList)
                    {
                        if (item.Name=="lbl_"+(rows.Index.ToString())+"_"+((p-1).ToString()))
                        {
                            str = item.Text;
                            ws.Cells[m, p] = str;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ws.Cells[m, p] = rows.Cells[p - 1].Value;
                }
            }

            m++;
        }

        ws.Columns.AutoFit();
```

This is my code from a school examination application. Hope this helps.